# What is the response received by IE for a duplicate post?

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, iis, post

If you visit an aspx web form, and click the submit button causing a POST to the server, then click submit again causing a second POST before receiving a response from the first POST, what happens in terms of the response? Does the server process both requests simultaneously or serially? Does the server send both responses? Does the browser ignore one of the responses? This may be self explanatory after an answer to the previous questions, but if I were to call Response.Clear(); Response.End(); for the second request, what would happen on the browser end?

Answer (score 1):

If there are no special means at the server side to handle multiple POSTs, the server will handle both requests independently. Whether or not the processing is concurrent - it depends:

- if your first POST causes the whole page to reload then it is impossible to trigger the second POST before the page is processed at the server side (because your second click is made from the page which is already at the client side)
- if your first POST causes an AJAX POST to the server and the processing takes some time at the server then it is possible that you end up with two POSTS from the same page processed concurrently at the server side

The server always sends responses and browsers do not ignore them. It is your code, at the server side or at the client side, to prevent such unintended multiple POSTs, for example by 302ing the response to another location which doesn't allow the user to rePOST the form.

Specifically, if you just clear the response (send an empty content) and the content type is `text/html` then the browser will render an empty page.

Comment: "if your first POST causes the whole page to reload then it is impossible to trigger the second POST before the page is processed at the server side" To me it looks like in IE if you click a submit button and then press f5 to reload before the response is received it will post the same form again. I've looked at using a [PRG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern, but I don't see how that eliminates the problem of a user resubmitting before a response is received. If you look at the diagram, all they've done is change when in the process the user refreshes.

Comment: The reason I'm asking is I have a form that disables the submit button after it's clicked, but I'm trying to build in a fail safe on the server side. Though not perfect, what I've done is add a token to the page on first load. On postback, check if the token is in session state, if not, add it and continue. If it is, I want to ignore the request. I would still need the browser to receive the response from the first initial request though and I'm still not clear on whether it would. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can someone tell me if the way I'm disabling this button would in any way allow a duplicate postback?

                    `<asp:Button ID="btnProcess" runat="server"
                    Text="Process" OnClick="btnProcess_Click" OnClientClick="OnProcessing(this)" UseSubmitBehavior="False"/>`

`function OnProcessing(button) //
            {
                //Check if client side validation passes before disabling

                button.disabled = true;
                window.external.OnPaymentProcessing();
            }`

We are continuing to see evidence of duplicate postbacks using this.

Answer (score 0):

I would say just about any of those things could happen, depending on the exact timing.

I believe calling Response.Clear(); Response.End(); on the second request would cause an empty response which the browser would receive, possibly after receiving the results of the first request.

Comment: It looks like in my case, when I call return; on the second request, the browser abandons or ignores or does not receive the response from the first request and only gets the second.

Comment: It's possible that, due to buffering and network, the browser receives the second response before the first.